# Parametrizing a Hyperbola

Tags: multivariable-calculus, conic-sections, parametrization

Consider the hyperbola determined by $$\Big(\frac{y-k}{b}\Big)^2-\Big(\frac{x}{a}\Big)^2=1.$$ The foci are at $(0,k \pm\sqrt{a^2+b^2}).$ Let's parametrize the upper half of the hyperbola by $$x=t,y=k+b\sqrt{1+\Big(\frac{t}{a}\Big)^2},$$

and define $r(t)=\langle x(t), y(t)\rangle.$
Under this parametrization I have $$r'(t)=\Bigg\langle 1, \frac{bt}{a^2\sqrt{1+\Big( \frac{t}{a}\Big)^2}}\Bigg \rangle$$ so that the speed is given by $$\vert r'(t) \vert=\sqrt{1+\frac{b^2t^2}{a^4\Bigg(1+\Big(\frac{t}{a}\Big)^2\Bigg)}}.$$

However, the speed is smallest when the point is near the foci (at time $t=0)$ and grows as $t\to \pm \infty$, counter to what I was expecting.

Is there a way to parametrize the hyperbola so that it reaches its maximum speed near the foci?

Comment: One could just use the parameterization given by the trajectory of an orbiting body. In particular, the body's maximum speed is achieved when the distance to the parent body (interior focus) is minimized.

Comment: Is there a way to modify the parametrization I already have to give that result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  I will work with the simpler equation $y^2-x^2=1$  We note that the slope of this is monotonically increasing from $0$ at the vertex toward $1$ as $x \to \infty$  Let $y=1+t, x=\sqrt{y^2-1}=\sqrt{t^2+2t}$  Then $v=\sqrt{x'^2+y'^2}=\sqrt {\frac{(t+1)^2}{t^2+2t}+1}=\sqrt{2+\frac 1{t^2+2t}}$ is a decreasing function of $t$, so decreasing as we get away from the vertex.

Comment: For any point $(c,d)$ on the hyperbola is it possible to parametrize it so that the max speed happens there?

Comment: Absolutely.  First parameterize it by arc length, so the speed is uniform everywhere.  I don't know if there is an easy formula, but that is a well defined function.  Let $s$ be the arc length and measure it from $0$ at $(c,d)$  Now let $s=t^{(1/3)}$ so $s$ increases fastest around $t=0$